# Reverse the order of integration.

Tags: integration

Reverse the order of integration:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{2\sqrt{x}}^{2\sqrt{x}+1} f(x,y)dydx$$.

This is my solution:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\frac{y^2}{4}}f(x,y)dxdy+\int_{1}^{2}\int_{\frac{(y-1)^2}{4}}^{\frac{y^2}{4}}f(x,y)dxdy+\int_{2}^{3}\int_{1-\frac{(y-1)^2}{4}}^{0}f(x,y)dxdy$$

But it dosen't work. What am I doing wrong? I think my third integral is bad. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to graph the region over which you are doing the integral. In the original case, you fix a value of $x$, and integrate over the values of $y$ between the two parabolas $y = 2\sqrt{x}$ and $y = 2\sqrt{x} +1$, and then varying $x$ from 0 to 1

Now, instead, let us fix a value of $y$. Then, we have the following cases

$$0 \leq y \leq 1$$
$$0 \leq x \leq \frac{y^2}{4}$$

This you've got right

Then,

$$1 \leq y \leq 2$$
$$\frac{(y-1)^2}{4} \leq x \leq \frac{y^2}{4}$$

This is also okay

Then,

$$2\leq y \leq 3$$
$$\frac{(y-1)^2}{4} \leq x \leq 1$$

This is where the mistake was done. The region would be bounded on the left by the upper parabola, and is not from 0 to 1 like in your attempt